# BeagleBone Black shows error "Package 'cmake' has no installation candidate"

Tags: cmake, makefile, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, debian-buster

When I try installing cmake on a BeagleBone Black board. I am using `Debian Buster IoT Image 2020-04-06`

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

I got the below error. For more details, this is my log:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo apt-get install cmake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package cmake is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'cmake' has no installation candidate
debian@beaglebone:~$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Please help me to install `cmake`.

Comment: This is not a makefile issue.  This is a package installation issue.  I assume you've done an `sudo apt update` in the recent past so you know you have the latest list of packages?

Comment: Right. @MadScientist , one would need to update/upgrade and then `sudo apt install PACKAGE` where PACKAGE is cmake in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...so. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` will allow for you to install cmake or you can use an updated version of the image from docs.beagleboard.org and/or forum.beagleboard.org which both have images available for their boards.

Also...

https://forum.beagleboard.org/tag/latest-images is a link with the latest images for the am335x supported BeagleBone Black. Once you have a Bullseye or Bookworm image, you can then update/upgrade and conversely use `apt` to install packages.

I think, personally, since Buster is EOL (End of Life) and not heavily supported any longer from their .org and repos, it might be difficult to find exactly what you are looking to attain without update/upgrade like @MadScientist pointed out.

Again, if you cannot install via `apt` your favorite package, in this case it is cmake, I would suggest installing it via their installation methods online found here: https://cmake.org/files/ `and here:` https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases .

You may have to figure out what `cmake` release works with Buster Distros of Linux while still being able to install it correctly and that is solely without the `apt` install variation.

So, if you go to the Debian Buster Distro repos online and look up your kernel and image, you can find what exact or around what exact versioning is needed.